# What index should I use when using JOIN on PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimise the following MySQL query

```
SELECT Hotel.HotelId, Hotel.Name, Hotel.Enabled, Hotel.IsClosed, 
HotelRoom.HotelId, HotelRoom.RoomId, HotelRoom.Name AS RoomName
FROM Hotel
INNER JOIN 
   HotelRoom ON Hotel.HotelId = HotelRoom.HotelId    
WHERE Hotel.IsClosed = 0
AND Hotel.Enabled = 1
AND HotelRoom.Deleted = 0
AND HotelRoom.Enabled = 1
AND IF(LENGTH(TRIM(sAuxiliaryIds)) > 0 AND sAuxiliaryIds IS NOT NULL, 
FIND_IN_SET(Hotel.AuxiliaryId, sAuxiliaryIds), 1=1) > 0 
ORDER BY Hotel.HotelId ASC, HotelRoom.RoomId ASC
```

The PRIMARY KEYS are `Hotel.Hotel` and `HotelRoom.RoomId`, and I've got a FOREIGN KEY from HotelRoom.HotelId to Hotel.HotelId.

Should I be creating a INDEX for `(Hotel.IsClosed, Hotel.Enabled)` and `(HotelRoom.Deleted, HotelRoom.Enabled)` which is used in the WHERE clause, and should this index include the PRIMARY key so for example I should create a INDEX for `(Hotel.HotelId, Hotel.IsClosed, Hotel.Enabled)`

**EDIT 1**
I've added the following in the WHERE statement `AND IF(LENGTH(TRIM(sAuxiliaryIds)) > 0 AND sAuxiliaryIds IS NOT NULL, FIND_IN_SET(Hotel.AuxiliaryId, sAuxiliaryIds), 1=1) > 0`  Should these also be included in INDEX

This is what the EXPLAIN statement is showing for this query

[image]

I added both INDEX suggestions but when I ran the EXPLAIN statement they both showed that no key was going to be used

[image]

Comment: Oooo, you can "delete" a Room?  I bet that is exciting to watch.  Does it involve explosives?  Or a big crane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's Optimizer does not care which table comes first in a `JOIN`.  It will look at statistics (etc) to decide for itself whether to start with `Hotel` or `HotelRoom`.  So, you should write indexes for both cases, so as not to restrict the Optimizer.

MySQL almost always performs a `JOIN` by scanning one table.  Then, for each row in that table, look up the necessary row(s) in the other table.  See "Nested Loop Join" or "NLJ".  This implies that the optimal indexes are (often) thus:  For the 'first' table, columns of the `WHERE` clause involving the first table.  For the `second` table, the columns from both the `WHERE` *and* `ON` clauses involving the second table.

Assuming that the Optimizer started with Hotel:

```
Hotel: INDEX(IsClosed, Enabled)   -- in either order
HotelRoom:  INDEX(Deleted, Enabled, HotelId)  -- in any order
```

If it started with HotelRoom:

```
HotelRoom:  INDEX(Deleted, Enabled)  -- in either order
Hotel: PRIMARY KEY(HotelId)  -- which you already have?
```

If there are a lot of closed/disabled hotels, then this may be beneficial:

```
Hotel: INDEX(IsClosed, Enabled, HotelId)
```

As Tim mentioned, it may be beneficial to augment an index to include the rest of the columns mentioned, thereby making the index "covering".  (But don't do this with the `PRIMARY KEY` or any `UNIQUE` key.)

If you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the sizes of the tables, we might have further suggestions.

Comment: There are a lot of closed/disabled hotels. If I created `Hotel: INDEX(IsClosed, Enabled, HotelId)` does the order matter in this instance, and say in the future a `WHERE` clause used the columns in a different order

Comment: @neildt - Put the two flags first, in either order.  This will help the filtering (`WHERE`).  Then put `HotelId` last.  The Optimizer treats `WHERE x AND y` the same as `WHERE y AND x`; that is, it checks both ways.  The order in the `INDEX` does matter in some situations, but not in your situation, other that what I just said.

Comment: When discussing indexing, I try to be very precise -- saying both what is necessary, and what is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for this.  If I created the INDEX `Hotel: INDEX(IsClosed, Enabled, HotelId)`, but also had this in the WHERE statement `AND IF(LENGTH(TRIM(sAuxiliaryIds)) > 0 AND sAuxiliaryIds IS NOT NULL, FIND_IN_SET(Hotel.AuxiliaryId, sAuxiliaryIds), 1=1) > 0` should I include this column as well ?

Comment: @neildt - No.  It is buried in a function call, so no index will help.

Comment: Adding `Hotel: INDEX(IsClosed, Enabled, HotelId)` has made a massive difference. Should I also consider adding `HotelRoom: INDEX(Deleted, Enabled, HotelId)`

Comment: Yes, add that index, too.  (It may not make a "massive" difference.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential indexing strategies here, depending on which of the two tables appears on the left side of the inner join (either table could potentially appear on either side of the join).  Given that the `HotelRoom` table likely contains many more records than the `Hotel` table, I would suggest placing the `Hotel` table on the left side of the join.  This would imply that the `Hotel` table would be scanned, and the index used for the join to `HotelRoom`.  Then, we can try using the following index on `HotelRoom`:

```
CREATE INDEX hotel_room_idx ON HotelRoom (HotelId, Deleted, Enabled, Name, RoomId);
```

This should speed up the join substantially, covers the `WHERE` clause, and also covers all columns in the select on `HotelRoom`.  Note that the following simplified index might also be very effective:

```
CREATE INDEX hotel_room_idx ON HotelRoom (HotelId, Deleted, Enabled);
```

This just covers the join and `WHERE` clause, but MySQL might still choose to use it.

Comment: I've also just added the EXPLAIN statement.  Sorry what do you mean by 'I would suggest placing the Hotel table on the left side of the join. '

Comment: If I read correctly, it appears that no indices are currently being used.  If you like, you may try my suggestion and then comment if it works or not.

Comment: Do I not need to consider a index for the `Hotel` table ?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your second question; I just saw it now.  The thing is, MySQL has to scan something, so it might as well be the smaller `Hotel` table.  The crux of my answer should make the join operation way faster than it currently is.  And the columns I include should make sure that this index contains all information needed to do the entire query.

Comment: OK thanks.  Is there any downside if I add a INDEX for `(Hotel.HotelId, Hotel.IsClosed, Hotel.Enabled)` as well for the `Hotel` table ?

Comment: Well, I don't think MySQL would use both indices at the same time, but no, there is no downside to adding it, other than that it would take up more space in your database, and possibly slow down updates and inserts a bit more than just having one index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry what do you mean by 'I would suggest placing the Hotel table on the left side of the join. '

Comment: MySQL has to start the query by scanning one of the two tables first.  I am suggesting that we try to setup an indexing strategy which scans the smaller table first, using the index to deal with the larger rooms table.