# Why is MySQL 'Sending Data' taking 1.3 seconds for 4116 rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-ec2, innodb, amazon-rds

Following on from a previous post  [What index should I use when using JOIN on PRIMARY KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425866/what-index-should-i-use-when-using-join-on-primary-key) where I asked for assistance in optimizing our query.   We are now experiencing an issue with MySQL 'Sending Data' taking longer than we expect for just 4116 rows of data.

Our database is running on AWS RDS instance t2.medium, and our application plus where I'm running the query from (MySQL Workbench) is running on t2.medium EC2 instance both in the same availability zone.

At first, I thought the issue was network related.  But I upgraded both instances to t2.large and still the same result with no improvement.  I also created an AWS MySQL Read Replica which obviously had no load, but the results were the same.

Here is the MySQL `EXPLAIN` statement

[image: MySQL EXPLAIN Statement]

If I export the data into a CSV format, the file size is 1.17mb.  Below is `SHOW profile` result where you can see 'Sending Data' is 1.332113

[image: MySQL Profile Result]

How can I improve the time it is taking to send this data?

**UPDATE**

I've carried out some further tests. I have created a new EC2 instance t2.medium, which is running Windows 2012 R2 and I have installed the same version of MySQL 5.6.40 locally on this server.  I've restored our current database from the live environment and ran the same query. The results are as follows :

> MySQL 5.6.40 running on Windows 2012 R2 instance

`2254 row(s) returned 0.015 sec / 0.672 sec`

> MySQL 5.6.40 running on RDS instance (t2.medium)

`2248 row(s) returned 0.047 sec / 1.469 sec`

The query was run using MySQL Workbench, and `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`. You can see that there is a big improvement in performance, saving over 900ms off the time.

I also created another Ec2 t2.medium instance running Windows in the same Az as i-060e68836b3320629, and installed MySQL Workbench. I ran the same query from this instance 'over the internal network' and the query time was the same e.g `2254 row(s) returned 0.015 sec / 0.682 sec`

Therefore our RDS instance is either experiencing some bottleneck issue, or the MySQL server settings need tuning.  I’ve also tried upgrading our RDS storage type to General Purpose SSD but still the same result.

Therefore I think the issue is related to the MySQL configuration.  Here is a list of the differences for `SHOW VARIABLES` for both the RDS and Ec2 instances.

[image]

Which of these `SHOW VARIABLES` do I need to change in order to resolve this issue?  Can someone please offer some guidance please.

Comment: Why is some information in the explain blurred?

Comment: That is just the database name, that relates to our company

Comment: which 4116 records are sended we know nothing? Not the query not the table structures nothing.. Sorry we can't help you without extended information.

Comment: Do you mean column names in the SELECT statement..

Comment: no i mean the complete query which you execute and we need `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` (so we know columnnames/datatypes/indexes) for every table involved in that query..

Comment: it looks like a network issue, does it happen as well when you do the same query from the machine where is mysql hosted ?

Comment: We are using AWS RDS MySQL running on t2.medium instance on both RDS and EC2.  I'll edit the question to include this information.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Our database is average around 40 concurrent connections 24/7.  So do you think this issue is network related, rather than anything to do with the query/table structure/indexes..

Comment: The label "Sending data" is misleading, it doesn't really have much to do with network transmission.

Comment: @Barmar It seems I've been following my tail thinking first it is to do with the query and that it needs to be optimized and then thinking it is network related...

Comment: *"The label "Sending data" is misleading, it doesn't really have much to do with network transmission. "* @Barmar now i reconsider his comment this indeed seams to be output of `SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY <>` which should time local thread stats.. *" Sending data

The thread is reading and processing rows for a SELECT statement, and sending data to the client. Because operations occurring during this state tend to perform large amounts of disk access (reads), it is often the longest-running state over the lifetime of a given query. "*

Comment: The question I linked to is about the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`. I'm assuming it has the same meaning in `SHOW PROFILE`.

Comment: well i am pretty sure it means the same @Barmar MySQL explains [general thread stats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-thread-states.html) it would be bad if the meaning if the thread state *"Sending data"* would change meaning between statements...

Comment: @RaymondNijland With MySQL, you never know :)

Comment: *" With MySQL, you never know :) "*  indeed you never know ;-) @Barmar to give a [example (post off mime)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54178/how-to-get-rid-of-using-temporary-when-using-distinct-in-mysql/54184#54184) .. Not related to this question shows that MySQL explain sometimes tells lies...

Comment: Face it!  `PROFILE` is useless.  There are only two or three states that any query is in 99% of the time.  (Or about 99.98% of the time for your case.)  Useless.

Comment: To discuss why it takes 1.3s to deliver 1.2MB, let's see, as already requested, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.  (Redact as names as needed, but we will need to correlate columns in the query with datatypes and indexes.)

Comment: @RickJames I'm going to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` but for now I've just updated the question with further tests

Comment: Perhaps your results show that the bandwidth to the original AWS was 3 times as slow as the bandwidth to the Windows server.  Where is your machine located? 
 And each server located, geographically?  There could be issues with both the throughput and the latency.

Comment: They are all in the same region and Availability Zone.  Eg as if they are on same internal network. I’m sure the issue is either MySQL configuration or RDS bottle neck

Comment: Any chance I can get this question reopened, as I've added further information relating to `SHOW VARIABLES` of both Ec2 and the Rds instance.

Comment: @neildt Looking at the EC2 - RDS differences, tmp_table_size=288M in your RDS instance could help you reduce your 'sending data' time.  Please post to pastebin.com (to avoid SO character limit) from your RDS instance, TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; (after minimum of 24 hours of UPTIME) and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for RDS workload analysis.

Comment: @neildt On Sep 6, 2019 you indicated ~ 40 concurrent connections.  In that case give the RDS some thread breathing room with thread_cache_size=100 (suggested limit in 5.7 refman to avoid OOM).  This will also reduce your threads_created count significantly each day.

Comment: @neildt       2nd request, Please post to pastebin.com (to avoid SO character limit) from your RDS instance, TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; (after minimum of 24 hours of UPTIME) and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for RDS workload analysis.